# Let $f$ be an affine transformation. The fixed points are inside invariant lines?

Tags: geometry, affine-geometry

I'm studying geometry. We're classifying affinities, and my professor wrote: This affine transformation is an hyperbolic transformation. It has a fixed point and two invariant lines. The fixed point is inside the invariant lines, inside both of them.

My question is: Why the fixed points are inside invariant lines? Is this fact true with planes and invariant lines? Is this general or it only happens on this particular case?

Thanks!

Comment: A fixed point. But how I know that this two lines are not parallel? Or, in higher dimensions, how I know that they intersect?

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=b$. We know $f$ is of the form $f(x)=Ax+v$ for some matrix $A$ and vector $v$.

Moreover, the line joining $a$ and $b$ is $\{ta+(1-t)b|t\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Then

$\begin{eqnarray*}f(ta+(1-t)b)&=&A(ta+(1-t)b)+v\\
&=&tAa+(1-t)Ab+v\\
&=&tAa+tv\\
&&+(1-t)Ab+(1-t)v\\
&&-tv-(1-t)v+v\\
&=&tf(a)+(1-t)f(b)\\
&=&ta+(1-t)b
\end{eqnarray*}$

Then, all the line is $f$-invariant.

Comment: This seems to show that if a transformation has two fixed points, then the line between them is fixed as well. (But it does not preclude some other line being fixed as well). But the OP's question seems to be "if a transformation has two (setwise) fixed lines, AND a fixed point, why must the fixed point be on both lines?" If you were in the projective case, you could plead duality, but we're in the affine case here.